# Dequeuing FIFOQueue in tensorflow always returns the same element

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, queue

I have some very stupid bug with tensorflow, am pretty sure that this is due to misusage of my side, but haven't found it in two days now. The code roughly goes like this:

```
train_gen = train_generator(X_train_n,indices_train_n)
```

train_generator is a python generator function (you can get the next element calling .next() ). I use it to preprocess batches from my raw data.

Before the session:

`queue_train_n = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=5,dtypes=[tf.float32,tf.float32]) 
enqueue_op_train_n = queue_train_n.enqueue(train_gen.next()) 
number_of_threads_train_n = 5
qr_train_n = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_train_n,[enqueue_op_train_n]*number_of_threads_train_n)
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr_train_n)`

Before the epochs start:

`coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)`

Then, within sess.run, I call  `model.train_dequeue_op` (model is the model's class) which executes `queue_train_n.dequeue()` and use this to store data in my "batch variables" self.X and self.y.

Now here is the weird thing: Whenever I call `model.train_dequeue_op` and look at the actual values retrieved (these are numpy arrays), they are exactly the same for every dequeuing operation. I have checked, whether `train_gen` is working correctly and it does: If I just yield the batches from train_gen in a for loop, they are always different. So apparently, the dequeue operation does only retrieve the value from the queue, but it isn't removed from this queue. Has anyone ever seen something like this and knows a solution? This is one of the weirdest bugs I have ever seen... If anyone just has an idea what to check, please let me know!

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Let me ask this question in a different way: Is there some way to check whether an element was actually dequeued from the tf.FIFOQueue?

Comment: Do tf queues not work with python generators together?

Comment: Can it be that generators don't work together with tf.Queues due to the multithreading for some reason?

Comment: I have the feeling that the dequeuing method is broken.

Comment: It appears like the generator is reset every time.